# How to avoid index rebuild on source table after exchange partition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

i have a daily job and this job is doing basically

1. LOAD Temp table
2. Exchange partition with source table
3. Rebuild local indexes
4. Rebuild global indexes

However, problem is that rebuilding indexes takes lots of time and this makes source table unavailable 
during this period. source table is very critical table to support real time application.
Because of this case, web services which uses this table getting time out exceptions.

Do i have any alternative way rather than building this indexes on source table ?

Any help or discussion is very appreciated.

You can find the code snipped of the daily job, and the structure of source table (TABLEX) and temp table 
(TABLEX_TEMP)

Daily Job:

`   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE X.LOAD__TABLES_X IS

```
BEGIN


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLEX_TEMP REUSE STORAGE';
   INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TABLEX_TEMP(CUST_NO ,IDNO,SEX,NAME,SURNAME)
   SELECT CUST_NO ,IDNO,SEX,NAME,SURNAME,PHONE
FROM T_X WHERE MAINT !='D';
COMMIT;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLEX EXCHANGE PARTITION DUMMY WITH TABLE TABLEX_TEMP WITHOUT VALIDATION';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLEX MODIFY PARTITION DUMMY REBUILD UNUSABLE LOCAL INDEXES';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX PK_CUST_NO REBUILD NOCOMPRESS NOPARALLEL TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX PK_CUST_NO_TMP REBUILD NOCOMPRESS NOPARALLEL TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX IDX_TABLEX REBUILD NOCOMPRESS NOPARALLEL TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX IDX_TABLEX_TMP REBUILD NOCOMPRESS NOPARALLEL TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLEX_TEMP REUSE STORAGE';

COMMIT;
END LOAD_TABLES_X;`
```

Structure of Tables and indexes :

`

CREATE TABLE X.TABLEX_TEMP
    (
      CUST_NO       NUMBER(9),
      NAME            VARCHAR2(54 BYTE),
      SURNAME         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
      SEX              VARCHAR (1 BYTE)
      IDNO            NUMBER(11)

```
)
TABLESPACE TS_X_DATAA
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    0
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          8M
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
LOGGING 
COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;


CREATE INDEX X.IDX_TABLEX_TMP ON X.TABLEX_TEMP
(IDNO)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          64K
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
NOPARALLEL;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X.PK_CUST_NO_TMP ON X.TABLEX_TEMP
(CUST_NO)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          64K
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
NOPARALLEL;


ALTER TABLE X.TABLEX_TEMP ADD (
  CONSTRAINT PK_CUST_NO_TMP
  PRIMARY KEY
  (CUST_NO)
  USING INDEX X.PK_CUST_NO_TMP
   ENABLE NOVALIDATE);

 ----------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE X.TABLEX
 (
   CUST_NO       NUMBER(9),
   NAME            VARCHAR2(54 BYTE),
   SURNAME         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
   SEX              VARCHAR (1 BYTE)
   IDNO            NUMBER(11)
 )
COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH 
TABLESPACE TS_X_DATA
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    0
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
PARTITION BY RANGE (CUST_NO)
(  
   PARTITION DUMMY VALUES LESS THAN (999999999)
   LOGGING
   COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH 
    TABLESPACE TS_X_DATA
    PCTFREE    0
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
   )
 NOCACHE
 NOPARALLEL
 MONITORING;


 CREATE INDEX X.IDX_TABLEX ON X.TABLEX
 (IDNO)
 NOLOGGING
 TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX
 PCTFREE    10
 INITRANS   2
 MAXTRANS   255
 STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          64K
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
 NOPARALLEL;


 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X.PK_CUST_NO ON X.TABLEX
 (CUST_NO)
 NOLOGGING
 TABLESPACE TS_X_INDEX
 PCTFREE    10
 INITRANS   2
 MAXTRANS   255
 STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          64K
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
        FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       )
 NOPARALLEL;



 ALTER TABLE X.TABLEX ADD (
   CONSTRAINT PK_CUST_NO
   PRIMARY KEY
   (CUST_NO)
   USING INDEX X.PK_CUST_NO
   ENABLE NOVALIDATE);
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since a partition exchange modifies a substantial part of the data the index has to become unusable. However, you can avoid the index to become unusable by updating the indexes during the partition exchange.

In my experience it is is best to use a two-step approach:

- Prior to the partition exchange you should build the same local indexes on the temporary table. Then you must append INCLUDING INDEXES to the ALTER TABLE command.
- If you do have to use global indexes you can update them during the partition exchange by appending UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES to the ALTER TABLE command. This will ensure that the global indexes are not unusable during the whole operation.

So you whole statement will become something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLEX EXCHANGE PARTITION DUMMY WITH TABLE TABLEX_TEMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

You may want to look at the official Oracle documentation for details:

- [Updating Indexes Automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-1D59BD49-CD86-4BFE-9099-D3B8D7FD932A.htm#VLDBG1122)
- [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2151566)